# how to correctly configure elseif syntax in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following situation in the blade where @elseif does not work even though it is configured correctly.

In html it takes me out as  instead of

[image]

```
@if ($posts->mime_type == ('video/mp4'||'video/quicktime'))
    <video loop muted autoplay class="item-img" src="../public/uploads/file_manager/{{ get_array_data($posts->cover_image) }}"  alt="Tutoriale cum sa creezi gratuit un site"></video>                        
@elseif ($posts->mime_type == ('image/jpg'||'image/png'))
    <image  class="item-img" src="../public/uploads/file_manager/{{ get_array_data($posts->cover_image) }}"  alt="Tutoriale cum sa creezi gratuit un site"></image>  
@else
    <div style="padding:100% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{ get_array_data($posts->video_url) }}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Gene fir cu fir Brasov"></iframe></div><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
@endif
```

Comment: Why not break your ```('video/mp4' || 'video/quicktime')``` to ```@if($posts->mime_type == 'video/mp4' || $posts->mime_type == 'video/quicktime')```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **first and second conditions** are being **ignored** because practically there will be no `mime_type` equal to `1`. see https://3v4l.org/kLvRR

```php
<?php
echo ('video/mp4'||'video/quicktime'); // Will show 1
```

That results in:

1. Only showing the video player with an actual video if the URL here `"https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{ get_array_data($posts->video_url) }}"` makes sense.
2. Otherwise you get a white card like the second and the third.

**Change your code to:**

```html
@if ($posts->mime_type == 'video/mp4' || $posts->mime_type == 'video/quicktime')
        {{-- ^^^^ --}}
    <video loop muted autoplay class="item-img"
        src="../public/uploads/file_manager/{{ get_array_data($posts->cover_image) }}"
        alt="Tutoriale cum sa creezi gratuit un site"></video>
@elseif ($posts->mime_type == 'image/jpg' || $posts->mime_type == 'image/png')
        {{-- ^^^^ --}}
    <image class="item-img" src="../public/uploads/file_manager/{{ get_array_data($posts->cover_image) }}"
        alt="Tutoriale cum sa creezi gratuit un site"></image>
@else
    <div style="padding:100% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{ get_array_data($posts->video_url) }}" frameborder="0"
            allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen
            style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" title="Gene fir cu fir Brasov"></iframe>
    </div>
    <script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
@endif
```

---

## Better conditions to check for images or videos generally

```php
substr($posts->mime_type,0 ,5) === 'video';
```

```php
substr($posts->mime_type,0 ,5) === 'image';
```

---

## Cleaner conditions for specific mime types:

```php
// Somewhere in your code
$my_videos_mime_types = ['video/mp4', 'video/quicktime'];
$my_images_mime_types = ['image/jpg', 'image/png'];
```

```php
in_array($posts->mime_type, $my_videos_mime_types);
```

```php
in_array($posts->mime_type, $my_images_mime_types);
```